# How to save bandwidth in a Zoom call?

Tags: video, bandwidth, zoom.us

I am working from home and my internet connection has a quota. I already turned off my video and would like to stop receiving the video feeds of others.

Can I make my Zoom audio-only? Or can I make it super-low resolution, or otherwise save bandwidth with Zoom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the web application, e.g on Chromium, you can click on the three dots and then on `Disable video receiving`. Then you can enable it again, and the menu looks like this:

[image: Enable video receiving]

The desktop application does not have such a feature as of this writing.