# Zoom on Chromium has no sound

Tags: zoom.us

I have been using Zoom on Chromium and last week it stopped producing sound. The sound output on the webpage was set to the built-in speakers. Other people can hear me and the Zoom application on the same machine and with the same meetings works well. (I use the browser to save data bandwidth, as in [How to save bandwidth in a Zoom call?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/139622/how-to-save-bandwidth-in-a-zoom-call)).

I uninstalled Chromium, restarted the machine, and reinstalled it with the same result. I also tried Google Chrome with the same result. I tried incognito mode with the same result on both. I have no extensions installed.

Has anyone else experienced this problem recently? Has anyone been able to fix it?

**Update**: I tried on Brave, another browser based on Chromium, I allowed Brave to access the microphone, and I have the same problem. My computer is `macOS 10.14.6` and the browser version is:

```
Brave is up to date
Version 1.11.104 Chromium: 84.0.4147.105 (Official Build) (64-bit)
```

In incognito mode, the microphone fills up with green at the beginning and then is completely blank when I talk into it. The video works and the other person could see me. I did not get audio from the other person either.

Comment: Yes, I have tried incognito mode and Google Chrome, both fail with the same problem. I have no extensions installed. I will try Brave Browser in two days and report on results.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that.